# Reshape wide data frame to long format in R using column name information

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reshape2, melt

I am having troubles converting a complicated data base output from its wide form to the long format. It has a couple of hundred rows and ~1,000 columns.
It looks something like this:

[image: wide df and melt result]

The problem is that the variable of df1_long or the columns of df1_wide contain information that I want to select upon. So I rather want to have something like this:

```
ID       part   task    subgroup    type    result
Ind_A       a     12          aa       2    yes
Ind_A       a     12          bb       2    yes
Ind_A       b     12          aa       3    opt_1
Ind_A       b     13          aa       4    100
Ind_B       a     12          aa       2    no
Ind_B       a     12          bb       2    yes
Ind_B       b     12          aa       3    opt_2
Ind_B       b     13          aa       4    50
Ind_C       a     12          aa       2    no
Ind_C       a     12          bb       2    no
Ind_C       b     12          aa       3    opt_1
Ind_C       b     13          aa       4    200
```

I dont mind that the numerical values/results get transformed into characters.

Is there a easy way to accomplish that with the stack() or reshape() function?
Or do I have to code a function that performes some strsplits commands on the column names to extract the relevant information and then store those in separate new columns.

The long format will definitely be much more easy to work with and ask questions to the data set. Coding something for >1000 columns with those cryptic columns names just looks like a nightmare to me.

Comment: Since you're already using "reshape2" and you've gotten this far, you could use the `colsplit()` function from the same package to split up the column appropriately. Some familiarity with regular expressions would be handy. Some sample data would increase your likelihood of getting meaningful help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok fine. I give in.

Here's your data:

```
df1_wide <- data.frame(v1 = c("Ind_A", "Ind_B", "Ind_C"), 
                       v2 = c("Y", "N", "N"), v3 = c("Y", "Y", "N"), 
                       v4 = c("op1_1", "opt_2", "opt_1"), 
                       v5 = c(100, 50, 200))
rownames(df1_wide) <- letters[1:3]
colnames(df1_wide) <- c("ID", "a_t12_aa (Type # 2)", "a_t12_bb (Type # 2)", 
                        "b_t12_aa (Type # 3)", "b_t13_aa (Type # 4)")
df1_wide
#      ID a_t12_aa (Type # 2) a_t12_bb (Type # 2) b_t12_aa (Type # 3) b_t13_aa (Type # 4)
# a Ind_A                   Y                   Y               op1_1                 100
# b Ind_B                   N                   Y               opt_2                  50
# c Ind_C                   N                   N               opt_1                 200
```

This is what you have done so far:

```
df1_long <- melt(df1_wide, id.vars="ID")
```

This is what it sounds like you want:

```
cbind(df1_long["ID"],
      colsplit(gsub("\\s|\\(Type|\\)|#", " ", df1_long$variable), 
               pattern="_|\\s+", 
               names = c("part", "task", "subgroup", "type")),
      df1_long["value"])
#       ID part task subgroup type value
# 1  Ind_A    a  t12       aa    2     Y
# 2  Ind_B    a  t12       aa    2     N
# 3  Ind_C    a  t12       aa    2     N
# 4  Ind_A    a  t12       bb    2     Y
# 5  Ind_B    a  t12       bb    2     Y
# 6  Ind_C    a  t12       bb    2     N
# 7  Ind_A    b  t12       aa    3 op1_1
# 8  Ind_B    b  t12       aa    3 opt_2
# 9  Ind_C    b  t12       aa    3 opt_1
# 10 Ind_A    b  t13       aa    4   100
# 11 Ind_B    b  t13       aa    4    50
# 12 Ind_C    b  t13       aa    4   200
```

I can't guarantee that the regular expression that I used with `gsub` will work with your actual data, but hopefully this is enough to point you in the right direction.

In the future, please note that sharing a screenshot of your data is pretty useless. Please share data as I did in this question, so that others can easily copy and paste to get started on trying to help you out.

---

You may want to consider that you rename your variables along the lines of `a_t12_aa_2`, in the future, in which case, the `colsplit` step would just be `colsplit(variable, "_", c("part", "task", "subgroup", "type"))`.

Comment: Dear Ananda, thank you very much. Not only for your solution, but also your advice and guide lines for future posts on my part. You produced exactly what I needed. I haven't heard of the colsplit function yet and I will defnitely want to learn more about reg expressions within the gsub function. Again, many thanks!